# Let f : X → Y and g : Y → Z be bijective mappings. Show that gf is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let f : X → Y and g : Y → Z be bijective mappings. Show that gf, the composition
of f and g, is bijective.

I have that since f(x)=y, and g(y)=z we get g(f(x))=g(y)=z is this enough to show gf is bijective?

Comment: Be more explicit.  Bijective means one-to-one and onto.  What does it mean for $g\circ f$ to be one-to-one?  What does it mean for $g \circ f$ to be onto?  Prove that these hold, separately.

Comment: You need to show injectivity. Also, the way you write it, it's not clear that you are proving surjectivity.

Comment: As stated, your argument merely asserts a property of arbitrary mappings (provided you say what $x$, $y$, and $z$ are, which at present you do not do).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to prove that the function is *injective* and *surjective*.

1. **Injective:** You must prove that, if $x,y\in X$ are distinct (i.e., $x\neq y$), then $g\circ f(x)\neq g\circ f(y)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are bijective, you know that they are injective. Thus, if $x\neq y$, then $f(x)\neq f(y)$. You now only have one step left to show that $g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))$ and $g\circ f(y)=g(f(y))$ are not equal to each other (use the injectivity of $g$).
2. **Surjective:** You must prove that, for any $z\in Z$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $g\circ f(x)=z$. Since $f$ and $g$ are bijective, they are surjective. Thus, for any $z\in Z$, there exists $y\in Y$ such that $g(y)=z$. (Now, use the fact that $f$ is surjective to complete the proof.)

Comment: "Thus, if $x \neq y$, then $f(x) \neq g(x)$." Is it possible that you meant to write $f(x) \neq f(y)$ here instead?

Comment: @Sid Absolutely! Thank you for letting me know. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one seeing that he meant that if it is true that the product of two bijective functions is bijective?